# Metadata isnt showing for opensea

Tags: solidity, contract-development, nft, mint, meta-data

Hey so I'm new to nft dev and decided I'll give it a try. I'm following the Hashlips NFT tutorial however it seems I am not getting the same results as him.

For some reason the "hidden"/"placeholder" image isnt showing up on opensea.

When I use the tokenURI call on remix for nft id: 1 I get this:

```
{
"0": "string: ipfs://QmWWfLiN8L6Hqa61BjL6aJ8SCTRXQxGfkAcYCvqttZqZ16/hidden.json"
}
```

Here is a copy of the JSON

```
    [
      {
        "name": "Best NFT Ever",
        "description": "Just simply the best ever NFT",
        "image": "ipfs://QmY34733FazEVvejVkHMkGXHB5utBZPcj9AtYvXatvTWwx/hidden.png",
        "custom_fields": {
          "total_mining_power": 220,
          "token_award": 696
        },
        "attributes": [],
        "external_url": "https:/bestnftever.com"
      }
    ]
```

However when I use the token meta validator (https://testnets-api.opensea.io/asset/0x59b5ed04b9bbf36d9522c900d3d2cb10dce7f768/1/validate/) I get:

```
    HTTP 200 OK
    Allow: OPTIONS, GET
    Content-Type: application/json
    Vary: Accept

    {
        "valid": true,
        "token_uri": null,
        "errors": []
    }
```

I feel like I'm missing something small and stupid but I can't figure out what it is. Any ideas?

Here is the link to the NFT on OpenSea: https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/goerli/0x59b5ed04b9bbf36d9522c900d3d2cb10dce7f768/1

P.S: I know its the holiday period so I am thankful in advance for the help guys and apologies if its a noobie question/mistake. I would really appreciate detailed answers so I can learn from and understand more how to debug etc...

P.S.S This project is new, however I have been trying this for a few days with different accounts incase opensea took time to get the data however it still isnt

Comment: it's hard to answer if you don't give any real file you uploaded. For privacy concern you can just upload a blank test.jpg img to ipfs instead of an invalid link like that.

Answer (score 1):

With limited information about the real file, I can only think of two possibilities at the moment:

1. the IPFS file may not work (e.g. the real link of ipfs://..../hidden.png may be invalid or some delay on Opensea side that you have to wait them a bit to fetch the file.
2. the json format may not be correct: the json string you printed out has array `[]`, are you sure it is a valid format?. A valid [BAYC 82 metadata](https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmeSjSinHpPnmXmspMjwiXyN6zS4E9zccariGR3jxcaWtq/82) is like this `object` without `array` `[]`. You may need to remove the square brackets.

```js
{
 "image":"ipfs://QmQU87VfXFej5WQdP8VUNGf1wrYhykcREPGBo37ox7zcGu",
 "attributes":[
  {"trait_type":"Clothes","value":"Service"},
  {"trait_type":"Earring","value":"Silver Hoop"}, 
  {"trait_type":"Background","value":"Army Green"}, 
  {"trait_type":"Mouth","value":"Jovial"}, 
  {"trait_type":"Fur","value":"Cream"},
  {"trait_type":"Eyes","value":"Sad"}
 ]
}
```

So your json may need to be like this

```
   {
        "name": "Best NFT Ever",
        "description": "Just simply the best ever NFT",
        "image": "ipfs://your_ifps_file",
        "custom_fields": {
          "total_mining_power": 220,
          "token_award": 696
        },
        "attributes": [],
        "external_url": "https:/bestnftever.com"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I should be using:

```
  {
    "name": "Best NFT Ever",
    "description": "Just simply the best ever NFT",
    "image": "ipfs://QmY34733FazEVvejVkHMkGXHB5utBZPcj9AtYvXatvTWwx/hidden.png",
    "custom_fields": {
      "total_mining_power": 220,
      "token_award": 696
    },
    "attributes": [],
    "external_url": "https:/bestnftever.com"
  }
```

Not

```
[
  {
    "name": "Best NFT Ever",
    "description": "Just simply the best ever NFT",
    "image": "ipfs://QmY34733FazEVvejVkHMkGXHB5utBZPcj9AtYvXatvTWwx/hidden.png",
    "custom_fields": {
      "total_mining_power": 220,
      "token_award": 696
    },
    "attributes": [],
    "external_url": "https:/bestnftever.com"
  }
]
```

My JSON is an array, should have been an object. *facepalm*

Comment: So my answer was correct and you didn't approve it